# Python Script in ArcGIS 10 is using module re and is returning "global name 're' is not defined"

Tags: python, arcgis, calculated-field, arcpy

I am new to python scripting and I mainly use it in ArcGIS 10.  My script is supposed to reformat a string within the Field CINTP1. An example would be '000000100' and return '1.00'. I have imported it into a toolbox to run on a selected record within the table 'MAPCHAR'.  The error I keep recieveing is:

: ERROR 000539: Error running expression: removeLeadingZeros("000000100") : global name 're' is not defined
Failed to execute (CalculateField).

Failed to execute (Script).

Here is my script:

```
import arcpy, re, sys, string, os

MAPCHAR = "MAPCHAR"

CINPT1 = "CINPT1"

expression = "removeLeadingZeros(!CINPT1!)"
codeblock = """def removeLeadingZeros(myValue):
    newValue = re.sub('^0+',"",myValue)

    valueList = list(newValue) #convert newValue to List
    valueList.insert(-2, '.') #insert the '.' characater int the list at the -2 position

    newValue = "".join(valueList) #join back to create the new  updated string

    myvalue = newValue"""

arcpy.CalculateField_management(MAPCHAR, CINPT1, expression, "Python", codeblock)
```

Any help would be appreciated..thanks,

Comment: I think you need to add import statement to your string `codeblock`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have your import statements in the below codeblock.. So add an `import re` as the first line in codeblock: -

```
codeblock = """import re
    def removeLeadingZeros(myValue):
        newValue = re.sub('^0+',"",myValue)

        valueList = list(newValue) #convert newValue to List
        valueList.insert(-2, '.') #insert the '.' int the list at the -2 position

        newValue = "".join(valueList) #join back to create the new  updated string

        myvalue = newValue"""
```

Comment: Thanks for your rapid response!  I added the import statement to the codeblock, but am now getting the an error for "name 'newValue' is not defined.  I thought it was being defined within the codeblock with the re.sub statement.  Again, I'm pretty new to this, thanks!

Comment: Ok...I found the problem.  I had a typo (myvalue = newValue should be myValue),but now when I execute the script in ArcGIS, it returns a null value into the field.

Comment: Should I be returning the myValue a different way before it's used in the arcpy.CalculateField?

Comment: @user1714326.. You can directly return `newValue`.. No need to assign it to myValue..

Comment: Sorry, I tried.  It said it requires a reputation of 15 and this is my first time on.  If I get up there, I'll get back to this thread and vote you up.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running `codeblock` in the arcpy namespace.  If arcpy doesn't have `import re` in it, `codeblock` wont work.

incidentally, you dont need regex to remove leading zeros-- just convert to an int.  Classic example of using a wrench to hammer a nail.

Comment: I'm also adding a "." to the string.  If you would have some sort of hint to an easier way to do this, I would definately consider it.  It seems that beginner Python scripting requires a lot of hammers!

Comment: you can insert a `.` into an arbitrary point in the string.

    `string[:-2] + "." + string[-2:]` inserts a `.` before the second to the last character.